# how can i install proton vpn on my pi

Tags: pi-3

I tried what customer support reccomentded, but it did not work.

```
sudo apt install -y openvpn dialog python3-pip python3-setuptools
[sudo] password for pi: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package dialog is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Unable to locate package openvpn
E: Package 'dialog' has no installation candidate
```

Comment: Which OS + version do you run? Doesn't looks like Raspbian. Also add the output of `apt policy` to your question.